# Como personalizar erros do PHP?

Tags: php, json

Estou tendo a seguinte dúvida, imagine que estou fazendo a requisição de um arquivo `JSON` externo através de um script `PHP`

```
<?php
    $json_file = file_get_contents("http://exemplo.com/arquivojson");
?>
```

E se esse arquivo, ou este site está fora do ar, então é retornado pra mim algo como:

> `Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/passagem/public_html/teste-ok.php on line 2`
>
> `Warning: file_get_contents(http://exemplo.com/arquivojson): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/passagem/public_html/teste-ok.php on line 2`

**É possível personalizar este erro ao não conseguir requisitar este arquivo?**

que ao invés de exibir este erro, apenas exibir um aviso, algo como:

> `Não foi possível localizar a informação desejada.`

Procurei e não encontrei nenhuma informação suficiente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se estes erros aparecem em seu servidor de produção é porque já está errado, agora se isto é no desenvolvimento então não tem porque "customizar", estes erros são para ajudar no desenvolvimento, para dar detalhes, para que os erros sejam corrigidos previamente.

Agora voltando ao produção, basta no php.ini ocultar (nunca desligue, tem certas respostas que vão recomendar para desligar, mas isto afeta os logs), então sete:

```
display_errors=off
```

Se a sua hospedagem tiver php_mod para Apache então pode fazer isto mais facilmente adicionando isto dentro do `.htaccess`:

```
php_flag display_errors off
```

> Note que se ocorrer um **erro 500** é porque tua hospedagem não tem o mod_php5 ou mod_php7

O `display_errors` irá apenas ocultar na página web, então ao usar o `file_get_contents` basta usar:

```
$json_file = file_get_contents("http://exemplo.com/arquivojson");

if ($json_file) {
   ... corre o script normal ...
} else {
   echo '<p>Não foi possível localizar a informação desejada.</p>';
}
```

---

### set_error_handler/set_exception_handler e register_shutdown_function

Esta parte da resposta é uma "precaução", se aparecerem outras respostas falando que pode customizar todos erros, sim você pode, mas não quer dizer que deva, isto porque os erros é como eu disse no começo, nem devem existir, se tem um erro em teu projeto logo ele deve ser corrigido, o quão antes possível no ambiente no desenvolvimento, se por acaso obtiver um erro em produção use os logs, pode usar o próprio do PHP, setando o:

```
error_log="/pasta/aonde/quero/salvar/log/erros.log"
```

Pode também usar nos if/else a função `error_log()` para lhe enviar um email: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php ou salvar em um arquivo

Você pode até interceptar os erros com `set_error_handler`, `set_exception_handler` e `register_shutdown_function` (este ultimo junto com `error_get_last()` para erros fatais), mas apenas para obter e salva-los aonde desejar

Comment: Na verdade estou utilizando uma API JSON externa, na qual se ela ficar indisponível ou o servidor ficar fora do ar temporariamente, ele vai exibir esse aviso, ao invés de exibir um erro, pois na verdade não seria um "erro" e sim estaria indisponível temporariamente.

Comment: @AlexandreLopes e o `display_errors=off` junto com o `if/else` resolve o problema exatamente desta sua necessidade de APIs eventualmente indisponiveis. **PS:** editei a resposta apenas para acaso apareçam certas respostas novas absurdas que podem lhe dar péssimas sugestões e lhe ensinar o pior caminho (acredite, tem muito disto no site :/).

Comment: Imagino Guilherme, irei fazer alguns testes. Muito interessante a resposta.

Comment: Seria possível fazer isso sem utilizar `display_errors` de forma mais dinâmica ?

Comment: @AlexandreLopes faça isto somente na hospedagem, não faça isso em desenvolvimento, não tem porque ser "dinamico", hospedagem=erros ocultos, seu computador=erros visiveis ... Agora se o intuito é ingnorar o warnings que não chegam a ser erros, adicione isto no topo do seu script principal: `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED);`, mas somente no script em produção, isso vai dentro do teu php é claro. Você pode criar um arquivo de configuração para dizer quando é ou não produção...

Comment: @AlexandreLopes ... crie um arquivo somente com o nome `production` e adicione no teu script algo como: `<?php if (is_file('production')) { error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED); }`, no teu computador o arquivo não deve existir. E reforçando, todos erros e warnings devem ser tratados em desenvolvimento, só erros eventuais e "normais" é que você provavelmente deve ocultar, para evitar instabilidades.

Comment: Desculpe Guilherme, não entendi muito bem. É possível criar um `echo` para exibir uma mensagem caso aconteça um erro?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102466/discussion-between-guilherme-nascimento-and-alexandre-lopes).

Comment: @AlexandreLopes sim é possivel, faça exatamente o que esta na resposta if e else

Comment: Tentei adicionar `error_reporting(0);` dentro do if e else para ocultar os erros, mas não funcionou. Como implementar?

Comment: Tentei assim: `if ($json_file) {
    
} else {
   error_reporting(0); echo '<p>Não foi possível localizar a informação desejada.</p>';
}`

Comment: Se ele conseguisse requisitar, tudo bem. Caso contrário ele adiciona `error_reporting(0);` o qual oculta os erros, e escreve `<p>Não foi possível localizar a informação desejada.</p>`

Comment: @AlexandreLopes como assim "não funcionou"? Explica melhor

Comment: @AlexandreLopes quem disse que era para por o error_reporting(0); põe o error_reporting no começo do script, antes de tudo.